# Given a number X , find two elements in two sorted arrays such A[i]+B[j] = X in O(n+m)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, big-o

Given the following problem , I'd appreciate for any corrections since I have no solution 
for the current question (taken from one of my professor's exams !!!) :

**Remark:** this is no homework !

**Problem:**

Given two sorted arrays `A` (with length `n`)  & `B` (with length `m`) , where each

element (in both arrays) is a real number , and a number `X` (also a real number) ,

we'd like to know whether or not exists `a ∈ A` and `b ∈ B` , such as :

`a + b = X`  , in `O(n+m)` running time .

**Solution :**

First , we start to check from the end of both arrays , since we don't need the numbers that are bigger than `X` :

- i = n
- k = m
- while A[i] > X , i = i -1
- while B[k] > X , k = k -1

Define j = 0 . 
Now start running from the current `i` in `A` , and from `j` in `B` :

- `while i > 0 , j < k`  :
- `if A[i]+B[j] == X` , then return both cells
- else `j = j+1 , i = i -1`

In the end we'd have either the two elements , or we'd reach out of bounds in one 
or both of the arrays , which means that no two elements such `a + b = X` are indeed exist .

Any remarks would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: maybe you can write down your entire algorithm in pseudo-code. The mix between english and pseudo-code confuses me.

Comment: Notice that you can omit the preprocessing. You can leave decrementing i to the main loop, and for j use a suitable loop condition (j ≤ m and B[j] ≤ X). You should not do any such optimization in cases where negative numbers are allowed in the arrays.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't adjust `i` and `j` at the same time. If the sum is too big, you should decrease `i`. If it is too small, increase `j`.

Comment: Great thing to notice.  However, doesn't this still lead to an O(n*m) solution?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: O(n+m) it was, and yes, it does. At each step you move in one array *or* the other array, so combined you cannot move more ofthen than the sum of both array lengths.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is a special case of the following question:
[Find number in sorted matrix (Rows n Columns) in O(log n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589975/find-number-in-sorted-matrix-rows-n-columns-in-olog-n?lq=1)

Consider a matrix filled with the `C[i,j] = A[i] + B[j]`, then starting from one of the corners, you decrease `i` if the sum is too big, and if it's too small, increase `j`.
Of course you don't have to create and/or fill this matrix `C` in your program, just assume you know any element of this matrix: it's `A[i] + B[j]`, you can compute it immediately at any moment. The resulting algorithm is `O(m+n)`.

Comment: I put a more concise question link :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question for homework.
I worked out before I check it on the internet.
Here is my solution(Python), hope some big guys see it and help me to improve it

```
# 1.3. Given two sorted arrays a and b and number S. Find two elements such that sum a[i] + b[j] = S.Time O(n).
```

def find_elem_sum(alist, blist, S):  # O(n)

```
if alist is None or alist == [] or blist is None or blist == []:
    return None

# find the numbers which are less than S in the lists
#
#
# pretend it is done

a_length = len(alist)
b_length = len(blist)
a_index, b_index = 0, 0
count = 0
while alist and a_index < a_length and b_index < b_length:
    count += 1
    if alist[a_index] + blist[b_index] < S:
        if a_index < a_length - 1:
            a_index += 1
        if a_index == a_length - 1:
            b_index += 1;
        continue
    elif alist[a_index] + blist[b_index] > S:
        alist = alist[:a_index]
        a_length = len(alist)
        a_index = a_length - 1
    elif alist[a_index] + blist[b_index] == S:
        return [a_index, b_index, count]

return None
```