# Algorithm-Find sum in matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time, sum

We are given 2D matrix array (let's say length i and wide j) and integer k
We have to find size of smallest rectangle, that contains this or greater sum
F.e k=7

4 1
  1 1
  1 1
  4 4

Anwser is 2, because 4+4=8 >= 7, if there wasn't last line, anwser would be 4, 4+1+1+1 = 7 >= 7

My idea is to count prefix sums Pref[k,l]=Tab[k,l]+Pref[k-1,l]+Pref[k,l-1]
And then compare every single rectangle

Is this possible to make it faster? My idea is T(n)=O(n^2) (Where n is number of elements in matrix)
I would like to do this in time n or n * log n

I would be really glad if someone would give me any tip how to do this :)

Comment: Your prefix sums don't seem to calculate anything meaningful.  Also if this problem could be solved in O(n^2) time as you claim, then it would be possible to solve the 2D maximum subrectangle problem in O(n^2 log U) time by binary searching on the largest value, where U is the sum of every positive number that appears in the input -- and that would be very surprising, since TTBOMK the state of the art for solving that problem is just a fraction under the O(n^3) generalisation of Kadane's algorithm to 2D.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Note that his `n` is the number of elements in the matrix, and not the size of one dimension.

Comment: Quite right @amit, my mistake.  I think the part about the prefix sums not calculating anything useful still stands though.

Comment: Yes, n is number of elements, my bad

Comment: @TheGrossSloth: That was *my* bad actually...  ;) You can define parameters how you want, I'm just accustomed to seeing n being the height (and width).

Comment: Ohh...ok, if we don't do it, for every  rectangle we have to count everything one more time, in my case , we can get anwser much faster  
F.e We have  rectangle from (a,b) to (c,d)
So Sum=Pref[c,d]-Pref[a,d]-Pref[c,b]+Pref[a,b]

Comment: The calculation you describe in your most recent comment (which is sometimes called "forming the integral image") is definitely sensible and a timesaver...  But it doesn't seem to bear any relationship to the calculation of Pref[] that you describe in the main post.

Comment: Finally, if all the elements of the array are positive, you should mention that!

Answer (score 1):

First, create an auxillary matrix: `sums`, where:

```
sums[i,j] = A[0,0] + A[0,1] + .... + A[0,j] + A[1,0] + ... + A[1,j] + ... + A[i,j]
```

I think this is what you meant when you said "prefix matrix".

This can be calculated in linear time with dynamic programming:

```
sums[0,j] = A[0,0] + ... + A[0,j]
sums[i,0] = A[0,0] + ... + A[i,0]
sums[i,j] = sums[i-1,j] + sums[i,j-1] - sums[i-1,j-1] + A[i,j]
                                            ^
                                     elements counted twice
```

Now, assuming all elements are non negative, this is non decreasing, matrix, where each column and each row are sorted.

So, iterating the matrix again, for each pair of indices `i,j`, find the value closest yet smaller than `sum[i,j]-k`.

[This can be done in `O(sqrt(n))`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10589975/572670).

Do it for each such `(i,j)` pair, and you get `O(n*sqrt(n))` solution.

Comment: Thanks for answer, in this problem elements are positive, but columns and rows are not sorted and that makes it harder :/

Comment: @TheGrossSloth The rows and columns of `sums` - the auxillary matrix you created are sorted. This is because the elements in the original matrix are all positive.