# Need a faster algorithm to count if a product is smaller than a given number

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I have the next problem:
My program reads two arrays and multiplies each element of the first array with each of the 2nd array. I have to count the number of results smaller than a given number. My code works correctly but i need to find a faster algorithm.

Here is my code:

```
void sort(int *array, int length)
{
    int index, jndex = 0, aux, compElPoz;
    for(index = 1; index < length; index++)
    {
        jndex = index - 1;
        compElPoz = index;
        while(array[compElPoz] < array[jndex])
        {
            aux = array[compElPoz];
            array[compElPoz] = array[jndex];
            array[jndex] = aux;
            if(jndex > 0)
                jndex--;
            compElPoz--;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    unsigned int n, in, jn, nr = 0, p, m;
    scanf("%u %u", &n, &p);
    int ar[n];//1st array
    for(in = 0; in < n; in++)
    {
        scanf("%u", &ar[in]);//reading the 1st array
    }
    scanf("%u", &m);
    int arr[m];//2nd array
    for(in = 0; in < m; in++)
    {
        scanf("%u", &arr[in]);//reading the 2nd array
    }
    sort(arr, m);//sorting the 2nd array
    for(in = 0; in < n; in++)
    {
        for(jn = 0; jn < m; jn++)
        {
            if(ar[in] * arr[jn] < p)
                nr++;
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", nr);
    return 0;
}
```

So i have to read ar[] and arr[] and p.
This is an example:

```
n = 5
p = 99
ar[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
m = 2
arr[2] = {34, 25}
```

The program will print 5 because 1 * 34 < 99, 1 * 25 < 99, 2 * 34 < 99, 2 * 25 < 99, 3 * 25 < 99.

Comment: This question belongs rather here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: sort ar[] array as well.

Comment: Did it but still not fast enough

Comment: @MichaelWalz do i have to delete it and ask it on codereview or can it be just moved?

Comment: @Timotei: Just sorting isn't enough, you must make use of the fact that the array is sorted. You can skip most of your inner loop by starting from where you left off before and then finding the next item in the sorted second array for which the product with the current item from the first falls below your threshold. You will traverse each array just once, but the second array will be traversed backwards.

Comment: what sorting algorithm u used to sort?

Comment: @ImranHossain I do not remember how the name of the algorithm I used but the code is in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that elements are positive.

1. Sort both arrays using fast sorting method (for example, library qsort()). Time complexity is `O(nlogn+mlogm)`
2. Imagine that you fill 2D table with results of multiplication. Note that every row and every column is sorted.
3. Find a place at the perimeter of that imaginary matrix for `given number` using binary search (or number itself if exists). `O(log(n)+log(m))`
4. Walk through matrix until another edge to separate bigger values from lesser values and count them. `O(n+m)`

Note that you should not calculate all matrix entries (to avoid quadratic complexity), just needed ones!

This is a kind of algorithm described [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-in-row-wise-and-column-wise-sorted-matrix/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589975/find-number-in-sorted-matrix-rows-n-columns-in-olog-n) (look at the excellent picture)

Comment: You can skip step 3 and keep the same complexity. Just start walking from top right, go to the left until the product becomes smaller, then go one down and repeat while summing up the distances to the left edge.

Comment: @maraca Yes, it was the first variant I wrote, then I just decided to show easy  way to start.

Comment: @MBo I think my code is faster because it stops when a value bigger than my 'p' is found. I mean it calculates only "asnwer + 1" products.

Comment: No, you are wrong. At first, you are using quadratic sorting method. Second - you algorithm checks up to M*N results, while counting problem does not require to find or output them all - just find a number.